# Stored Procedure returns an int when updating Model from Database in EntityFramework C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to return a List in my Web Method

My Stored Procedure "GetProductsByProductID" returns a two coloumns when executed from the SQL Server using EXEC sp_name @parameter

But when I update the Model from Database in the C# Context, I am getting int as the return.

I have tried, deleting the SP and creating again and then updating the model as well. Doesn't seem to work. Would be really helpful if anyone has a solution to this?

My SP Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProductNameIDsByProdNumber] (@prodList nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  DECLARE @Err int

  CREATE TABLE #tempProduct (
    ProductNumber int
  )
  INSERT INTO #tempProduct (ProductNumber)
    SELECT
      *
    FROM SplitString(@prodList, ',')

  SELECT
    c.ProductID,
    c.ProductName
  FROM dbo.Product AS c
  INNER JOIN #tempProduct
    ON c.ProductNumber = #tempProduct.ProductNumber

  DROP TABLE #tempProduct

  SET @Err = @@Error
  RETURN @Err
END

GO
```

Result when I did 
    EXECUTE GetProductNameIDsByProdNumber @prodList='1111,4545'

```
    ProductID     ProductName
    F6F1067B       ABC
    BD3B2D0A       XYZ
```

Model Generated SP, when I updated Model from Database in the context file

```
public virtual int GetProductNameIDsByProdNumber(string prodList)
        {
            var prodListParameter = prodList != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("prodList", prodList) :
                new ObjectParameter("prodList", typeof(string));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).
               ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("GetProductNameIDsByProdNumber", prodListParameter);
        }
```

Comment: In the stored procedure you are returning error "RETURN @Err" Entity framework is returning this value. use Try Catch in you stored procedure to catch the errors

Comment: And why is the `RETURN @Err` part there? Do you expect any input to cause exceptions?

Comment: No, I have removed that part or returning an error now, still have the same issue @GertArnold

Comment: I recommend you attach sql server profiler and capture the exact query that is being executed on the database server.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your procedure

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProductNameIDsByProdNumber] (@prodList nvarchar(max))
    AS
    BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON
      DECLARE @Err int

      CREATE TABLE #tempProduct (
        ProductNumber int
      )
      INSERT INTO #tempProduct (ProductNumber)
        SELECT
          *
        FROM SplitString(@prodList, ',')
        BEGIN TRY
             SELECT
            c.ProductID,
            c.ProductName
          FROM dbo.Product AS c
          INNER JOIN #tempProduct
            ON c.ProductNumber = #tempProduct.ProductNumber
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
           SET @Err = @@Error
          RETURN @Err
        END CATCH
END

GO
```

Comment: Tried this, still getting the virtual int as a return parameter in the context file.